# i need to retrieve last data row single data

Tags: sqlite, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I need to retrieve the last row one data field. `id` is the primary key of my table. I'm trying to retrieve my final row data using its id

```cs
public AddExpenses[] GetFinalExpense(int numberOfExpenses)
{
    return Conn.Table<AddExpenses>()
               .OrderByDescending(expenses => expenses.Id)
               .Take(numberOfExpenses)
               .ToArray();
}
```

In my view model I have

```cs
var finalexpense = database.GetFinalExpense(1);
```

this is my code. when I tried to use this final row data to retrieve single data

```cs
ExpenseLabel = "Your expense is"+finalexpense;
```

in here final expense it does not show properties of the table to call. I need my finalexpense property to call it does not work

Comment: `finalexpense`  will not show any property because `finalexpense` is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating a string with an object uses the default implementation of `ToString` which will yield something like `AddExpenses[]` for you, if `finalexpense` has a value `!=null`, since it is an array.

First of all, you'll have to get the item in the array

```
var finalExpenses = database.GetFinalExpense(1);
var finalExpense = finalExpenses[0];
```

Furthermore you'll have to make sure that your object is formatted properly. You could implement your own `ToString` method in `AddExpenses` class, but the simplest way would be to use string interpolation

```
var formattedExpense = $"{finalExpense.Expense} ({finalExpense.Date}, {finalExpense.Category})"; 
ExpenseLabel = $"Your expense is {formattedExpense}";
```

How you build `formattedExpense` is up to you, take the proposed string as a starting point and adapt it to your needs.